# How to check if Siebel has successfully delivered an email?

Tags: email, siebel

We send a lot of email messages from our Siebel 7.8 application, and we'd like to determine whether they have been successfully delivered or not.

[According to the Bookshelf](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/CommSrvAdm/CommSrvAdm_EmailOther8.html#wp1005586), if the SMTP server is down, the Communications Outbound Manager retries to send the message later, so that's not a problem. However, there are still plenty of issues which could cause an email to not be delivered, such as a typo in the address, the receiver having reached its storage quota, etc.

We send our messages this way:

```js
var ps = TheApplication().NewPropertySet();
ps.SetProperty("ActivityId", outboundEmailActivityId);
ps.SetProperty("CommProfile", commProfile);
ps.SetProperty("ProcessMode", "Local");

var bs = TheApplication().GetService("Outbound Communications Manager");
bs.InvokeMethod("SendMessage", ps, psOut);
```

Using `ProcessMode = Local` allows us to detect a few errors. For example, if we try to send a message to a non-existant account in the same domain of our SMTP server, it returns `550 Unknown user` and then `503 Must have sender and recipient first`. The Outbound Communications Manager raises an exception, and we capture and handle it.

However, if we send a message to a non-existant account in a different domain, our SMTP server can't know that it will fail, and therefore it returns `250 Queued`, and our code completes successfully. Later (it can range from seconds to a few hours later), we will receive a "Message undeliverable" error message, but at this point we only know that an outbound message failed, we don't know which one.

**Is there any way in which Siebel can handle these 'Message undeliverable' notifications automatically?**

We are thinking of writing our own process for that, but it seems like a huge task: we'd have to parse the delivery failure notification, identify the failing recipient, search for all the recent messages sent to that address, and somehow, guess which one failed (based on the Message-Id if we are lucky and can read it within Siebel, or on the Subject otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SMTP is by its nature neither a synchronous nor reliable protocol (i.e. in the sense of "engineered for guaranteed delivery").  Your Siebel app server will connect to its assigned SMTP server and ask it to accept a message for delivery and at that time there are a few high level validations that can be perform (some of which you've mentioned but which can also include policy enforcement such as checking whether your (possibly anonymous) identity is authorized for relaying messages to external domains).  Once that conversation ends, there is not much else you can reliably do because again, everything from that point is asynchronous and not guaranteed for delivery (any number of intermediate relay agents can be involved, each with their own potential for outages with or without retry, each with the ability to honor or ignore requests for delivery or read receipts or to report invalid recipients, throwing your message in a junk folder or not, etc.).  Certainly you can attempt to work with any bounce notifications you do happen to get to try to correlate them back to the sender but that would be outside the context of your sending code.